# QT Application as System App on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm porting our application using QT to the Android platform.  This is a kiosk-type application, the devices are rooted and we have full control over them.  In order to modify some system settings (networking in particular), our app needs to be installed as a system app.  To accomplish this, I use the following commands in an adb shell (after an adb remount):

```
1) pm install /data/my_app.apk
2) rm /data/my_app.apk
3) cp -p /data/app/com.me.my_app-1.apk /system/app
4) rm /data/app/com.me.my_app-1.apk
5) cp -p /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1/* /system/lib
6) rm -rf /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1
7) rm /data/data/com.me.my_app/lib
8) ln -s /system/lib /data/data/com.me.my_app/lib
9) reboot
```

After the reboot, when I launch the application I get a message box:

```
"Your application encountered a fatal error and cannot continue."
```

logcat shows the following exception and stack trace:

```
I/Qt      ( 1272): qt start
D/dalvikvm( 1272): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libmy_app.so 0x411f0a08, skipping init
W/System.err( 1272): java.lang.Exception: Can't find main library 'my_app'
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.startApplication(QtNative.java:196)
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.startApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:635)
W/System.err( 1272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:252)
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:643)
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:872)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
W/System.err( 1272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err( 1272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err( 1272):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1272): java.lang.Exception: 
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:253)
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:643)
W/System.err( 1272):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:872)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
W/System.err( 1272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err( 1272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err( 1272):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

libmy_app.so is located in /system/lib along with all the other QT libraries (libQt5AndroidExtras.so, libQt5Widgets.so, etc)

Googling for "Can't find main library" has led me to the QT source but that hasn't been helpful in tracking down why it can't find the library.

So any insight as to what's going on would be appreciated.  Or if there a a better, totally different solution to running a QT app as a system app, I'm open to that too.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

After some more investigation, it appears the problem is because QTNative.startApplication() is using nativeLibraryPath to look for libmy_app.so. nativeLibraryPath is defined in /data/system/packages.xml:

```
<package name="com.me.my_app" codePath="/system/app/com.me.my_app-1.apk" nativeLibraryPath="/data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1" flags="572999" ft="1471c4d74c0" it="1471c4d7c39" ut="1471c4d7c39" version="1" userId="10063">
```

but /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1 doesn't exist when my_app is a system app.  My first though was it's because I removed it in step 6 after moving the libraries to the /system/lib folder.  But even leaving that step out, after rebooting the device /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1 is gone.  I guess some Android package management process cleaned it up.  If I create a symlink from /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1 point to /system/lib after the reboot, my application runs.

So my question at this point is what is nativeLibraryPath in packages.xml used for?  It appears that Android searches for libraries via /data/data/com.me.my_app/lib, which is a symlink to either /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1 or /system/lib depending if it's a user or system app.  And I figured this out because if I don't move the Qt libraries to /system/lib and change the symlink (steps 5, 7 and 8) my application throws an exception even earlier because Android can't find the QT libraries.

But it appears QT is using the value of nativeLibraryPath from packages.xml to find my library.  Is changing it to /system/lib the correct solution?  Are there any other potential side effects?  Or is this a misbehaviour on QT's part and it should use the same search path as the rest of Android?

Answer (score 2):

I think the right solution is recreating the symlink from /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1 to /system/lib after the reboot.  It's only removed on the first reboot after moving the app to the system folder and is stable from that point across reboots and app updates.  So I'm going to mark this as the answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem.  For reference, the process I ended up with to install a QT app as a system app from the adb shell is:

```
1) pm install /data/my_app.apk
2) rm /data/my_app.apk
3) cp -p /data/app/com.me.my_app-1.apk /system/app
4) rm /data/app/com.me.my_app-1.apk
5) cp -p /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1/* /system/lib
6) rm /data/data/com.me.my_app/lib
7) ln -s /system/lib /data/data/com.me.my_app/lib
8) reboot
```

Start the adb shell again and then:

```
9) ln -s /system/lib /data/app-lib/com.me.my_app-1
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thank you so much for posting this!  A minor note for my setup... I copied onto `/sdcard/` initially, and my package manager `pm` installed it normally to `/data/app/`.

Comment: also, post Android 4.3, install to `/system/priv-app/` instead of `/system/app/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this patchset as a temporary solution: https://codereview.qt-project.org/194507
All libraries from android-build/libs/ must be deployed at /system/lib folder on device (or firmware before it built)

Comment: Actually he can't. I've just needed exactly that and it doesn't work on the LTS (5.9.6) when cherry-picked. What's worse, it doesn't work even on 5.10.1 (where the patchset is already present), the first version where I saw it working was 5.11.1