# How do I install a Qt app as a system app on Android?

Tags: android, qt

I'm building an embedded Android device and I have a `Qt/QML` app I'd like to install as a system app.

However, when I attempt to launch it after moving it to `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`, I get a popup box "Your application encountered a fatal error and cannot continue"

I tried this on the simplest QML project and as standard an emulator config as I could, and still ran into the issue

I'm doing this on Windows now as I write this question, but I also ran into the same issue trying to do it from my main Linux development machine.

Steps I followed leading up to this (some may be in a different order than they were actually performed, I'm recalling from memory after trial and error):

1. Install Android Studio Canary (2021.1.1 Canary 7)
2. Install Android 29 SDK and the x86 emulator image (Google APIs, not Google Play), create a Pixel 5 API 29 virtual device
3. Install Qt 5.15.2 for Android from the Qt maintenance tool / online installer
4. Install AdoptOpenJDK 8
5. Run Qt Creator, head to Tools->Options->Devices->Android, point it to the AdoptOpenJDK installation, let it set up the tools it needs, and verify everything has green checkmarks
6. Start a new project and select the Qt Quick "Swipe" template (bare minimum QML example), 5.15.2 for Android. Named "QMLhello" in this case.
7. In "Projects" tab under the "Build" settings for 5.15.2 multi-abi, expand the "qmake" section and check the "x86" checkbox so that it builds an ABI for the Android emulator
8. Verify that Qt Creator can build and run the app as a "normal" app (the green "Run" button successfully deploys and launches the app, and can swipe between pages)

Steps I performed in order to prepare to move the app to the system:

1. Add environment variable `studio.emu.params` to the user environment, with the contents `-writable-system`
2. Restart Android Studio and cold boot the AVD emulator to start with a writable system as specified in the environment variable
3. `adb devices` lists the emulator as a device
4. `adb root` and `adb remount` successfully remounts

What I tried after some rummaging around, combining some older answers on StackOverflow into my attempt:

```
adb shell
mv /data/app/org.qtproject.example.QMLhello-LpZtuoO0ejyQPg_I-8pWnQ==/lib/x86/* /system/lib
mv /data/app/org.qtproject.example.QMLhello-LpZtuoO0ejyQPg_I-8pWnQ== /system/app
```

**The contents of that lib directory were:**

```
generic_x86:/data/app/org.qtproject.example.QMLhello-LpZtuoO0ejyQPg_I-8pWnQ==/lib/x86 # ls -al
total 32892
drwxr-xr-x 2 system system    4096 2021-08-17 10:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 system system    4096 2021-08-17 10:48 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   18100 1981-01-01 01:01 libQMLhello_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 5885892 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5Core_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 4916776 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5Gui_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 1548420 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5Network_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  478836 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5QmlModels_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   47632 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5QmlWorkerScript_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 4236260 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5Qml_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  181004 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5QuickControls2_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 1392176 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5QuickTemplates2_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 4880080 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5Quick_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  562364 1981-01-01 01:01 libQt5RemoteObjects_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  931652 1981-01-01 01:01 libc++_shared.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   56196 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_bearer_qandroidbearer_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   26304 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qgif_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   34944 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qicns_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   22208 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qico_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  399040 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qjpeg_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   18112 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qtga_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  432080 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qtiff_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   18112 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qwbmp_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  673576 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_imageformats_qwebp_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 1200076 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_platforms_qtforandroid_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  150600 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_debugger_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   67868 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_inspector_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   14076 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_local_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   14076 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_messages_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   22332 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_native_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   45316 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_nativedebugger_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   84564 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_preview_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   63504 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_profiler_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   22268 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_quickprofiler_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   55248 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_server_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   14072 1981-01-01 01:01 libplugins_qmltooling_qmldbg_tcp_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   52096 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtGraphicalEffects_private_qtgraphicaleffectsprivate_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   50948 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtGraphicalEffects_qtgraphicaleffectsplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system    9928 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQml_Models.2_modelsplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   18128 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQml_RemoteObjects_qtqmlremoteobjects_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   69520 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQml_StateMachine_qtqmlstatemachine_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system    9932 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQml_WorkerScript.2_workerscriptplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system    9920 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQml_qmlplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system    9924 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick.2_qtquick2plugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  600836 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Controls.2_Fusion_qtquickcontrols2fusionstyleplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system 1611660 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Controls.2_Imagine_qtquickcontrols2imaginestyleplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  744164 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Controls.2_Material_qtquickcontrols2materialstyleplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  602016 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Controls.2_Universal_qtquickcontrols2universalstyleplugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  652988 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Controls.2_qtquickcontrols2plugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system  378820 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Templates.2_qtquicktemplates2plugin_x86.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system system   40492 1981-01-01 01:01 libqml_QtQuick_Window.2_windowplugin_x86.so
```

and Qt tries to load from /system/lib when running as a system app, so I needed to move them there (the patchset referenced in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44051918/2619499) was merged)

Here are the logs from logcat, from the moment I tap the app icon in the launcher to the time it appears to have terminated:

```
08-17 10:25:34.303  1965  4949 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.qtproject.example.QMLhello/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity bnds=[37,1236][238,1560]} from uid 10109
08-17 10:25:34.308  1965  2005 E system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
08-17 10:25:34.308  1965  1965 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } U=0: not found
08-17 10:25:34.308  1965  1965 W RemoteAppPredictionService: could not bind to Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } using flags 67108865
08-17 10:25:34.308  1965  2298 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
08-17 10:25:34.309  1965  2298 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder:1965_6 identical 28 lines
08-17 10:25:34.309  1965  2298 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
08-17 10:25:34.310  4888  4888 W ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e48f5bf
08-17 10:25:34.314  1965  2298 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
08-17 10:25:34.314  1965  2298 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder:1965_6 identical 8 lines
08-17 10:25:34.314  1965  2298 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
08-17 10:25:34.329  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 10108928
08-17 10:25:34.356  4888  4888 E Qt      : It looks like app deployed as system app. It may be necessary to specify path to system lib directory using android.app.system_libs_prefix metadata variable in your AndroidManifest.xml
08-17 10:25:34.356  4888  4888 E Qt      : Using /system/lib/ as default path
08-17 10:25:34.358  4888  4888 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
08-17 10:25:34.384  1965  2005 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
08-17 10:25:34.384  1965  2005 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) android.anim identical 8 lines
08-17 10:25:34.384  1965  2005 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
08-17 10:25:34.387  4888  4913 W System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-17 10:25:34.387  4888  4913 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$4.run(QtNative.java:495)
08-17 10:25:34.387  4888  4913 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$2.run(QtThread.java:87)
08-17 10:25:34.387  4888  4913 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:61)
08-17 10:25:34.387  4888  4913 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
08-17 10:25:34.387  4888  4888 W System.err: java.lang.Exception:
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.loadApplication(QtLoader.java:268)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp(QtLoader.java:505)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate(QtActivityLoader.java:166)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreateHook(QtActivity.java:267)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:274)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-17 10:25:34.388  4888  4888 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
08-17 10:25:34.389  4888  4888 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
08-17 10:25:34.438  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1495040
08-17 10:25:34.449  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.451  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.452  4888  4909 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3010e40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe2feea20)
08-17 10:25:34.460  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1495040
08-17 10:25:34.464  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1495040
08-17 10:25:34.466  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.469  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.479  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 10108928
08-17 10:25:34.483  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.489  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.492  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 10108928
08-17 10:25:34.493  4888  4909 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3010e40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe2feea20)
08-17 10:25:34.499  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.526  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.527  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.530  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.532  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.545  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.546  1754  2456 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 10108928
08-17 10:25:34.548  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.561  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.563  4888  4909 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3010e40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe2feea20)
08-17 10:25:34.565  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 19 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.569  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.583  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.584  1965  2009 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed org.qtproject.example.QMLhello/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity: +255ms
08-17 10:25:34.586  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.599  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.611  1755  2673 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.616  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.618  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.633  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.634  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.635  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.640  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.649  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.651  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.652  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.655  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.666  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.668  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.670  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.673  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.683  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.685  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.685  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.691  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.699  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.701  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.704  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.709  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.716  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.718  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.721  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.725  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.733  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.735  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.741  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.746  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.750  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.752  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0612d20
08-17 10:25:34.757  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.761  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.766  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.768  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf0613080
08-17 10:25:34.772  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.775  2120  2352 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f6dde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc15443d0)
08-17 10:25:34.783  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 20 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-17 10:25:34.786  1755  1755 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xf06130e0
08-17 10:25:34.848  1768  1768 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{607c35c token=Token{3592dcf ActivityRecord{84abe2e u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t8}}})/@0x2c802ff - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
08-17 10:25:34.848  1768  1768 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{607c35c token=Token{3592dcf ActivityRecord{84abe2e u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t8}}})/@0x2c802ff - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
08-17 10:25:34.848  1768  1768 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{8151314 token=Token{6bf8967 ActivityRecord{6996926 u0 org.qtproject.example.QMLhello/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity t11}}})/@0x8dbcc29 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
08-17 10:25:34.848  1768  1768 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{8151314 token=Token{6bf8967 ActivityRecord{6996926 u0 org.qtproject.example.QMLhello/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity t11}}})/@0x8dbcc29 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
08-17 10:25:34.850  2955  3141 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f75c00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbeb4d200)
08-17 10:25:34.852  2308  2944 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2f66840: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe3005990)
08-17 10:25:34.867  2955  3134 I PBSessionCacheImpl: Deleted sessionId[497328440469] from persistence.
08-17 10:25:34.889  2955  3112 W SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
08-17 10:25:34.898  1768  1768 W SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
```

That line of code it references in the exception, [QtLoader.java line 268](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/android/java/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtLoader.java?h=5.15.2#n268), simply appears to throw an empty string exception if it fails to "invoke", without any information on why it failed to invoke.

Digging further, it looks like the cause comes from [QtNative.java line 495](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/android/jar/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative.java?h=5.15.2#n495) where it runs into a NullPointerException attempting to call info.metaData.containsKey. But I can't fathom why that would fail for a system app when it doesn't fail for a normal app.

**What else am I missing?**

Comment: And from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24685920/295004 did you copy to `/system/priv-app` rather than `/system/app`. Related: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist

Comment: @MorrisonChang ah, yes, tried that too, sorry should've mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was moving the libraries to `/system/lib`. I believe I may have blindly copied all the steps of a previous answer where that was necessary, and some changes in Qt and/or Android may've have happened since then that lead to my issue.

For my purposes, **it was sufficient to simply move the directory altogether as-is** from `/data/app/` to `/system/priv-app`, keeping the library subdirectory.

```sh
adb install appname.apk
adb remount
adb shell
cd /data/app
mv appname* /system/priv-app
reboot
```

The QtLoader is able to load up some of the shared libraries from `/system/lib` enough to get to the next step. But the next step needs to have the libraries in the first place it looks, at `/system/priv-app/org.qtproject.example.QMLhello-LpZtuoO0ejyQPg_I-8pWnQ==/lib/x86` (at least in the case of the x86 emulator - substitute other arch as needed)

Otherwise, there is a chance it will run into a `NullPointerException` and fail to launch.

### Potential workaround

Add some `<meta-data>` directly under `<application>` in **AndroidManifest.xml**

### Details

Here is a snippet of the QtNative.java code, lines 489-497 as of the 5.15.2 release (line numbers added)

```java
// ...
/* 489 */ File f = new File(nativeLibraryDir + mainLibNameTemplate);
/* 490 */ if (!f.exists()) {
/* 491 */     try {
/* 492 */         ApplicationInfo info = getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
/* 493 */                 .getApplicationInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
/* 494 */         String systemLibraryDir = QtNativeLibrariesDir.systemLibrariesDir;
/* 495 */         if (info.metaData.containsKey("android.app.system_libs_prefix"))
/* 496 */             systemLibraryDir = info.metaData.getString("android.app.system_libs_prefix");
/* 497 */         f = new File(systemLibraryDir + mainLibNameTemplate);
// ...
```

489: When QtNative.java goes to load the main application library, it first checks in that `./lib/x86` subfolder, in this case.

492-493: When it fails to find that, it's looking for some metadata in the application manifest to see if the application is telling it where to look. When there is no metadata at the application level, however, the `metaData` member of the object is null.

495. Not checking for null, thus a `NullPointerException` gets thrown

### How did a null pointer happen in the first place?

The **AndroidManifest.xml** generated by Qt by default for this project (attached below) does not contain any `<meta-data>` tags directly under the `<application>` level--they are instead contained in `<activity>`. The `loadMainLibrary` function should be looking at the `activityInfo` instead of (or in addition to) `applicationInfo`, as well as checking for null beforehand.

This seems like a bug in Qt and I'll report accordingly, but 5.15.x won't be getting any more updates for open source.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="org.qtproject.example.QMLhello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default features based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default features. -->
    

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="QMLhello" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="QMLhello" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Application arguments -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="arg1 arg2 arg3"/ -->
            <!-- Application arguments -->

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="QMLhello"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>

            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/load_local_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="jar/QtAndroid.jar:jar/QtAndroidBearer.jar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value=""/>
            <!-- Used to specify custom system library path to run with local system libs -->
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="android.app.system_libs_prefix" android:value="/system/lib/"/> -->
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/unsupported_android_version" android:name="android.app.unsupported_android_version"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->

            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!-- Orientation-specific (portrait/landscape) data is checked first. If not available for current orientation,
                 then android.app.splash_screen_drawable. For best results, use together with splash_screen_sticky and
                 use hideSplashScreen() with a fade-out animation from Qt Android Extras to hide the splash screen when you
                 are done populating your window with content. -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_portrait" android:resource="@drawable/logo_portrait" / -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable_landscape" android:resource="@drawable/logo_landscape" / -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/ -->
            <!-- meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/ -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->

            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                          application still try to draw after
                          "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                          signal is sent! -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- Background running -->

            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.auto_screen_scale_factor" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- auto screen scale factor -->

            <!-- extract android style -->
            <!-- available android:values :
                * default - In most cases this will be the same as "full", but it can also be something else if needed, e.g., for compatibility reasons
                * full - useful QWidget & Quick Controls 1 apps
                * minimal - useful for Quick Controls 2 apps, it is much faster than "full"
                * none - useful for apps that don't use any of the above Qt modules
                -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="default"/>
            <!-- extract android style -->
    </activity>

    <!-- For adding service(s) please check: https://wiki.qt.io/AndroidServices -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```